# Laravel does not commit my second transaction

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, transactions

I have some troubles understanding why does not commit both transactions.

I have a application that is running MYSQL database with autocommit disabled;

During one request, I do two transactions, lets say:

```
public function createDownload($user_id,$filename,$path){
$response = null;   
try {
    DB::transaction(function () use ($filename,$path,$user_id) {
    $output = DB::table($this->table)->insert(array('file_name' => $filename, 'path' => $path,'user_id'=>$user_id));
    $this->response = $output;
    });
        DB::commit();
        DB::disconnect('mysql');
        return $this->response;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return False;
    } 

}
public function finishedDownload($filename,$path){
    DB::reconnect('mysql');
    $response = null;
    try {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($path) {
            $output = DB::table($this->table)->where('path', '=', $path)->update(array('status'=>1));
            $this->response = $output;
        });
        Log::info($this->response);
        DB::commit();
        return $this->response;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        Log::error($e->getMessage());
        return False;
    } 

}
```

In this case, lets say in one request from a user, Controller A call both methods in the same request:

```
createDownload(1,toto,toto/toto);
----
----
lines of code
----
----
finishedDownload(toto,toto);
```

It should basically, in the first method, insert the record, and after few lines of code, update the same record.

BUT! It insert the record, and commit, but then when suppose to update it, it does not update the record!
When i check what the query returns after update, it returns 1 confirming that the query went ahead, but it does not do the commit();

Can anybody explain me the reason why, and how I can fix this bug?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you disconnecting and reconnecting? Why are you not using eloquent queries? Why are you using transactions for single queries and then ending those transactions?

Comment: (Couldn't edit last comment) : Transactions are used for data integrity- meaning that they're only necessary when running multiple queries that should execute successfully all together, or not execute at all. Using them for single transactions is unnecessary and will use resources that it doesn't need. Eloquent would make your life much, much easier.

Comment: disconnecting from the db will rollback any outstanding transactions, unless you're using persistent connections (bad idea). and when you reconnect, there's NO guarantee you'd get the same connection that your first query used, meaning you'd potentially be connecting to some completely DIFFERENT transaction.

Comment: If my Database has disabled the autocommit feature, how do I commit the any changes in my code without doing transactions?

Comment: DB::beginTransaction()  and then commit and rollback.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different thing with just transaction() without any luck, I did use beginTransaction() and close them with commit or rollback. 
This way was successful.
Thank you!